# How to resolve issue in order by date

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  SELECT COUNT(patient_id) AS idpateint,
    patient_id
  FROM patient
  WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_enter,'%d/%m/%Y' )
      BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE( '$repeat','%d/%m/%Y' ) AND STR_TO_DATE('$to','%d/%m/%Y')
  AND patient_type='opd'
  AND patient_id  ='$idpatient1'
  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_enter,'%d/%m/%Y' )
```

Actually I saved date in dd/mm/yyyy format in db. Order by is not working. No SQL error but date is not coming in order.

Comment: Did you store the date (the value) as a `DATE` (the data type)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query:

```
select count(patient_id) as numpatients, patient_id
from patient
where STR_TO_DATE(date_enter, '%d/%m/%Y' ) between STR_TO_DATE('$repeat', '%d/%m/%Y' ) and 
                                                  STR_TO_DATE('$to', '%d/%m/%Y') and
       patient_type = 'opd' and
       patient_id = '$idpatient1'
order by STR_TO_DATE(date_enter, '%d/%m/%Y' )
```

You have a `count()` in the `select`.  This turns the query into an aggregation query, so it only returns one row.  In addition, you are selectxing only a single patient id.  I could imagine that you want the counts by date, because you are so focused on `date`.

The following will give counts by date, regardless of the patient:

```
select STR_TO_DATE(date_enter, '%d/%m/%Y' ), count(patient_id) as numpatients
from patient
where STR_TO_DATE(date_enter, '%d/%m/%Y' ) between STR_TO_DATE('$repeat', '%d/%m/%Y' ) and 
                                                   STR_TO_DATE('$to', '%d/%m/%Y') and
       patient_type = 'opd' and
group by STR_TO_DATE(date_enter, '%d/%m/%Y' )
order by STR_TO_DATE(date_enter, '%d/%m/%Y' );
```

By the way.  Don't you think the query looks ugly with all those calls to `STR_TO_DATE()`.  They are ugly in addition to making the query less efficient.  Store dates in the database using the database data types.  That is what they are there for.